# Synergy 1.5.0 Windows 8 & 7

Tags: windows

I'm trying to connect two computers with Synergy v1.5.0: Windows 8 (as the server) and Windows 7 (as the client). When I start the server there's no problem, but on the client's screen Synergy says:

> "WARNING: failed to connect to server: Timed out".

I configured it on the server's side by having one screen next to the other on the Configuration Panel.

- I made sure is the same port on both computers: 24800.
- I have taken the IP from the command line (cmd then ipconfig) and set it on each PC.
- I have tried to turned off the firewall but didn't work out.

Don't know what else to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posted on behalf of the OP.*

I have solved this by installing Synergy 1.3.1 that can be found on Sourceforge: (http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy2/) and following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OixCfusCiuA).

Comment: Or here: https://github.com/dagelf/productivitytool/blob/master/SynergyInstaller-1.3.1.exe

But you'll need to install this same old version on all PC's.